# How to replace vent tee under kitchen sink

Tags: plumbing, garbage-disposal, kitchen-sink

My garbage disposal empties into a trap. Before the trap, my other sink drain joins with a vent tee. I am assuming this in incorrect. Occasionally, the trap does not empty fast enough and water + food climbs up into the horizontal run of pipe, causing it to clog. I am also assuming that I need to replace the vent tee with a sanitary tee.

My problem is that I can not find a replacement sanitary tee that has the top threaded. I also can not find a male adapter that maintains the proper diameter. I am seeking advice on how to redo this.

[image]

[image]

Come to think about it, is this plumbing arrangement even allowed? The waste from the other drain, along with the dishwasher discharge flows into the line from the disposal. Isn't it normally the other way around?

[image]

Comment: That looks like a [center-outlet Tee](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-1-2-in-Plastic-Center-Outlet-Waste-Slip-Joint-Tee-C9186B/205153707) which has been turned on its side so that its outlet is being used as an inlet and one of the inlets as the outlet. If you unhook it and look through from one side to the other, is there a plastic 'baffle' in the middle preventing you from seeing straight through?

Comment: It was a few years ago when I took it apart, but I'm quite sure there was not a baffle in the middle. I'd remember that.

Comment: Nevermind - After a closer look at your bottom pic I can see that it's not. The bottom slip-joint nut would be facing the other way.

Comment: Watch what you put into the disposer. Too many leafy green too fast can "plug up " the drain giving you the problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the tee with a sanitary tee. Use couplers to create threaded ends on the tee.

Answer (score 1):

> Occasionally, the trap does not empty fast enough and water + food climbs up into the horizontal run of pipe, causing it to clog.
>
> I am not sure anything can be done to prevent this besides good garbage disposal habits.

This would be good for starters. Go slower and make sure the other sink is open to allow air to enter.

I don't think replacing that Tee with a Sanitary Tee is going to make any difference without redesigning the whole drain system.

If you still have problems after going slow on the disposal, you might consider separating the two sink drains into individual traps.

Also, your dishwasher discharge hose should have an air gap or at least a high loop to prevent back flow if the drain backs up.

Good luck!

Comment: I do need to get the hose higher up for the air gap, but I need to replace the hose with something more rigid.  The current hose could kink and reduce flow right now.

Comment: Usually you use fiberglass reinforced hose that resists kinking and fasten it on place with tubing clamps.

Answer (score 0):

Answering for reference:

The dishwasher discharge hose got clogged, so I had to dissemble the plumbing.  The vent tee does in fact have a baffle in the inside of it.  I think when the trap clogged in the past, water and food must have made its way up the other drain and into the discharge hose.  Separate issue, but it made me take the pipes apart.  I am not sure anything can be done to prevent this besides good garbage disposal habits.